# Swift - Send array to PHP

Tags: php, swift

I want to send an array to my server with URLRequest post method but it doesn't work.

When I send a string it works well but with an array not work. I can't get data with array post.

Below code works great:

```
func getData() {
    
    pageid = 1
    
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://localhost/index.php")!, cachePolicy: .reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData, timeoutInterval: 60)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    
    let postString = "page=" + String(pageid);
    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
    
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
        
        do {
        
            let response = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
            
            let itemsArray = response["items"] as! [AnyObject]
            
            for itemObj in itemsArray {
                print(itemObj)
            }
        } catch {
        
        }
        
    }).resume();
}
```

my array is:

`var ids: [Int] = [1, 5, 8]`

i try to send it like this but it doesn't work

`let postString = "page=" + String(ids.description)`

my php code:

```
<?php
    $pageid = $_POST['page'];
    ....
?>
```

Comment: What format do you expect in your url? Perhaps doing `ids.joined(separator: ",")` would work? Or should you perhaps encode the array into json but then I guess you don't need `&page=`?

Comment: $pageid= $_POST['page']; I get data with this code in php and I use this code wherever I want. @JoakimDanielson

Comment: Why are you starting your `postString` value with an `&` - when there aren't any parameters before that? `let postString = "&page=" + String(ids.description)` - what did that actually result in, what value does `postString` really contain now when you check?

Comment: Maybe you misunderstood me, I meant maybe `&page=` wasn't needed when sending json but then again it's a bit confusing when it looks like you are sending a url query parameter as the http body and not as part of the url.

Comment: i forgot to delete it while cleaning the complex code structure. not working even if there is no "&" @CBroe

Comment: I need to send it with 'key' to my php. @JoakimDanielson

Comment: Then add it to the url

Comment: can I do this with the post method?